# Animated Loading Icon in the System Generated "Preview Window" on Android

Tags: android, android-animation

As we know that in Android, an application's "preview window" is generated by the system on the application/activity's style (http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=873).

Is there a way to get a rotating wait icon in this "preview window"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. there's no way. you can apply only styling attributes, no actual layout or views.